# How to get MySQL data to update once "next" button is pressed?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I cannot seem to understand why this pagination with PHP & MySQL isn't switching data to the next page once the button is pressed, even though on the header it goes to the next page ex: site.com/index.php?page=2

```
postClass {

    //the __construct is on the class as well, just showing what isn't working under it.

    private $perPage = 8;
    private $startPage = 0;

    public function latestPosts(){
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
        $sth->execute(array($this->startPage, $this->perPage));

        $data = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }

    public function getPerPage(){ 
      return $this->perPage;
    }

    public function getStartPage(){ 
      return $this->startPage;
    }
}
```

and on another php file I am using the following to show the data

```
$startPage  = $postClass->getStartPage();
$perPage    = $postClass->getPerPage();

if(!isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = 1;
} else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

if($page <= 1)
{
    $startPage = 0;
} else {
    $startPage = $page * $perPage - $perPage;
} 

foreach($latestPosts as $post)
{
    $title = $post['title'];

    echo ''.$title.'';
}

$prev = $page-1;
$next = $page+1;

echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>previous</a> <a href='?page=$next'>next</a>";
```

I have tried print_r & var_dump to see what it prints but it seems to work fine, just that the data doesn't seem to be passing into the if(page) statement, from what I can think of, but I'm no expert otherwise it would work.

Here is what print_r & var_dump shows.

```
var_dump($perPage) = int 8
print_r($perPage) = 8

var_dump($startPage) = int 0
print_r($startPage) = 0
```

I don't understand why once I press the next button the data(8 first results) doesn't switch to the next 8 results.

### other failed attempts

I have also tried this which I figured would work but I couldn't pass the variable to the other functions..

```
public function latestPosts(){
    $perPage = 8;
    $startPage = 0;

    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $sth->execute(array($startPage, $perPage));

    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}

public function getPerPage(){ 
    eturn $this->latestPosts($perPage);
}

public function getStartPage(){ 
    return $this->latestPosts($startPage);
}
```

then did the same thing on the `index.php` page but errors were giving that I couldn't figure out how to pass those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you go to page 2, you want to select "next" 8 records, but your sql query `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?` will always select the same records.
WHat you need is `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Offset tells sql how many rows it should skip before selecting. For example for page 2 it should be 8 ( `offset = (current_page - 1)*per_page`)

Here you can find basic pagination tutorial:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Comment: also you can just use `limit $start,$offset`

Answer (score 0):

You never set `postClass::$startPage` and `postClass::$perPage`. Those fields are no pointers.

You assume this would change the fields:

```
$startPage  = $postClass->getStartPage();
$perPage    = $postClass->getPerPage();

if(!isset($_GET['page']))
{
   $page = 1;
} else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
```

It doesn't. PHP works per value on primitives (unless you explicitly use `&`). Just implement setter and work with them:

```
class postClass {

    public function setStartPage($page) {
        $this->startPage = $page;
    }

}

if (! isset($_GET['page'])) {
     $postClass->setStartPage(1);

}
```

BTW have a look at PSR code conventions, in particular [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Comment: After 8 hours, I still haven't been able to understand what is so wrong that I have been doing. Sheesh. Following this again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
//PostManager class
public function getLatestPosts($startPage=0, $perPage = 8){
    $this->startPage = $startPage;
    $this->perPage = 9;

    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $sth->execute(array($startPage, $perPage));

    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}

//main page
$posts = getLatestPosts($start, $perPage); //however you define $start and $perPage
foreach($posts as $post) { /* ... */ }
$next = $page+1; $prev = ($page > 1) ? $page-1 : 0; //if we are not in the beginning
```